# Store important data in internal storage

Tags: android

I'm trying understand which is the best way to store sensitive data in Android. In my app i want to insert a classic in-app-purchase model with some coins. My problem is that i'm not sure how to implement this correctly.
The initial idea was to simply use my firebase database, store the number of coins for every user and fetch the data every time the app is launched. This way I can easily detect some inappropriate usage but my users are forced to use the internet to play.
Looking at the documentations, I found [this](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files#java). Can this be a solution? Can I save in the internal storage the number of coins, maybe with some type of encryption, to avoid root user to modify the file? Then when the internet is on I can double-check the local stored variable with the the one in the database.
Thanks

Comment: you have some solutions, one of them is `File` with encryption, or you can use `sqlite` db with encryption, and there is some ways fro encrypting data

Answer (score 1):

Not an "easy" task. 
Technically, you can create a SecretKey and encrypt data, so no normal user will be able to reproduce. If your concern are root users, You are kind of out of luck, as he can hook into your app while it is reading/writing that value.

But to store it online is not a solution in itself. You have to answer questions like: "Do you trust any server input"?
"How to make sure just paid coins are added"?

Have you had a look at [Google Play billing](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview)?

it provides safe way's to determine if somebody paid or not. 
This will require to be online.

Comment: It's the first question I asked to myself. The problem is always that building from scratch your own platform is cost and time consuming. Using Google resources seemed the right compromise. As you said my first concern are root user. I know how this works, users have powerful tool like freedom and lucky pathcher. These days everyone with an internet connection and some basic skills can potentially be a problem for the developer. From the start I knew that my system can't be secure at 100%, I'm trying to understand what can I do to avoid problems with the most part of the users.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a sensitive data to save you can use sqlcipher database .. the good with it that it encrypt the database file itself so even the root user be able to get the database file he will not be able to decrypt it if you use a secured encryption algorithm.
you can find more about sqlcipher here
https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/

Comment: You can hook into the encryption part of the app as root. Hence it is NOT secure

Comment: @RafaelT Did you be able before to decrypt it? .. as I worked with it before on many projects so if it is not secured what should I use instead?

Comment: As a root user, using tools like "xposedframework" you can hook on *any* method of your app. Before, after, and during execution. Unfortunately the only thing you can do is to detect and deny root users, or using a safe and secured online mechaninsm.

Answer (score 0):

Since I assume you will grant your app a reading permission of your sensitive data and all writing processes should be reserved server-side, I would not recommend storing the data in a file on a phone, though every encryption can potentially be passed.

Maybe you already have heard about `SharedPreferences`, which is a good solution for let's say Preferences the user selects and that only shall affect his particular installation of your app. The difference is, that values are not stored in an external file, so not that easy accessible, BUT your app needs to write them, due only the app can access them directly (also your server can't).  I am not aware of how your sensitive data is used at all but I would also not use `SharedPreferences` since it's injective-prone.

Official docs about [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences/).

If security of your data (speaking of Confidentiality, Integrity, Authentication) is your No. 1 priority, simply don't store your sensitive data on the users device. Focus more on creating an API that ensures secure and performant passing of the relevant bits of your sensitive data. Hope this helps to give you a view of which way to go and which to walk around.